# Using Bing Aerial With API Key in QGIS

Tags: api, gis, bing-maps, qgis, pyqgis

I want to use Bing Satellite images in QGIS using the Bing Maps API. You can do this in ArcGIS with not much bother using the API key. I'm sure it must be possible to do this in QGIS but can't work it out.

It's easy enough to get low quality maps in but I want the high-resolution ones offered using Bing API.

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

1. Go to Layer > Add Layer > Add XYZ Layer.
2. Click New
3. Name as Bing Maps(as you wish)
4. URL as [https://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a{q}.jpeg?g=1&key=[YourBingMapskey]](https://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a%7Bq%7D.jpeg?g=1&key=%5BYourBingMapskey%5D)
5. Click Ok
6. Select XYZ Connections as Bing Maps (Which you created now)
7. Click Add